# How to centre a text view in Horizontal linear layout?

Tags: android-linearlayout

Well, I referred many sites and questions, I tried them but still I can't get the right alignment what i need. I want a text view with centre at the horizontal orientation in a linear layout.

Below is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fifteen_dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_icon"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/subscribe"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/header" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to overlap Textview over Imageview then You should try it with RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.
LinearLayout arranges Views according to their orientation.
You can try `weightsum` and `layout_weight`according to your design.

Here is Sample i created for you: [image]

Code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".3" />

<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:text="Center Text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".4" />

<ImageView
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".3" />
```